# Creating a search function to return a NaticScript list view using javascript

Tags: arrays, search, nativescript, searchbar

Good day all, I've been playing with NativeScript and I can't seem to get the .xml  to connect to the .js code behind page.

**The final goal** is to create a list page which can be searched, returning only items with matching data. It sounds easy, I've tried a series of fancy code bits and I'm down to basic for loops =S.

Please any assistance would be greatly appreciated, I'd like to keep whatever hair I have left.

The NativeScript searchBar attributes are here: https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_search_bar_.searchbar.html

They also provide this code, which I believe is typescript:
https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/ui/search-bar

Here is my NativeScript .js code behind

```
var searchBarModule = require("ui/search-bar");
var dialogsModule = require("ui/dialogs");
var observableModule = require("data/observable")
var ObservableArray = require("data/observable-array").ObservableArray;
var page;

var pageData = new observableModule.fromObject({
    list: new ObservableArray([
        { name: "one" },
        { name: "two" },
        { name: "three" },
        { name: "one one" }
    ]),
    searchtxt:"Search items"
});

exports.loaded = function(args) {
    page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = pageData;
};

exports.searched = function() {
  var searchtxt = pageData.searchtxt;
  var list = pageData.list;

  for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    if(list[i].indexOf(searchtxt)!=-1){
        var newlist.push(searchtxt);
        console.log(newlist);
    }
  }
};
```

And my XML front facing page

```
<Page loaded="loaded">
  <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
    <Image src="res://logo" stretch="none" horizontalAlignment="center" />
      <SearchBar id="searchBar" hint="Search" text="{{ searchtxt }}" clear="onClear" submit="searched" />

      <GridLayout>
        <ListView items="{{ list }}">
            <ListView.itemTemplate>
                <Label text="{{ name }}" horizontalAlignment="left" verticalAlignment="center"/>
            </ListView.itemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </GridLayout>

    </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

Thank you kindly

Comment: Can you double check the name of xml file and js file?

Comment: File names are correct, they are titled contents.EXT and so is the containing folder. Good thinking though. The XML reads the list and it appears. I think my search function is the problem exports.searched = function() {.

Answer (score 0):

If the list appears, it means that the XML has read it right. The problem should be inside your searched function. Have you tried to `console.log` the `searchedtxt` to see if it's right, because you don't have any setter for property `searchedtxt` of `pageData`?

However, I suggest passing the `args` as a parameter of function `searched` so that you will get the text exactly (`args.object` is UI component, which is Search Bar in this case).

One more thing, based on the searched text, you create a new list that contains items which match the requirement but you don't set that list to `pageData`, which is `bindingContext` of the page. In other words, you created a new list but you don't tell the page to receive that list as data. Here is my suggestion for your question, hope it works:

In `.js` file:

```
// Separate to the originalList so that you can set it to pageData again when user clear the search
var originalList = new ObservableArray([
        { name: "one" },
        { name: "two" },
        { name: "three" },
        { name: "one one" }
    ]);

var pageData = new observableModule.fromObject({
    list: originalList,
    searchtxt:"Search items"
});

exports.searched = function(args) {
  var searchtxt = args.object.text;
  pageData.list = new ObservableArray();

  for(var i = 0; i < originalList.length; i++){
    if(originalList[i].name.indexOf(searchtxt) !== -1){
        pageData.list.push(pageData.list[i]);
        console.log(pageData.list);
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestions and the code, you are a champion and I think you've addressed some of the issues with my code. I've plugged in your code and this is where I get stuck.

Exports.searched function, the for loop runs but if I console log originalList.name[i] the app crashes( Segmentation fault: 11 ), if I console log originalList.name I get undefined 4 times. If I console log originalList I get [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]. So it sees the array and it's items but it's undefined when queried specifically.

Answer (score 0):

I actually moved away from NativeScript and to phonegap. It was much simpler to implement, and the code runs as expected.

My basic javascript solution code for a search function can be viewed on Plunker here:
https://plnkr.co/edit/RnLYElvk2LaOY0KnePlN?p=info

This is my general search function solution:

```
function searchFor() {
  searchedItems = [];
  searchTerm = document.getElementById('searchBox').value;
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    if (data[i].ID.includes(searchTerm) || data[i].DATA.includes(searchTerm)) {

      listToShow.push({
        "ID": data[i].ID,
        "LINK": data[i].LINK
      });
      listLinks.push(data[i].LINK);
      searchedItems.push('<p><a href="#" onclick="loadPage(' + data[i].LINK + ');">' + data[i].ID + '</a></p>');

    }
  }
  document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = searchedItems;
}
```